# Laravel relationship for user with multiple scenarios

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So, i need to make relationship between users table, roles and sections table, the table structure as follows :

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string
    role_id - foreignId
    section_id - foreignId

sections
    id - integer
    section - string
    department - string

roles
    id - integer
    title - string
```

User model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function section()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Section::class);
    }
    
    public function role()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
}
```

The model above is OK if the user only belongsTo one section.
The problem is user can belongs to more than one section depending on their role.
The role itself determine this matrix below

[image: the matrix]

How can i achive this ?

Comment: can a section have many users?

Comment: @lagbox yes, of course

Comment: you will need to setup a Belongs To Many between them, which would need a pivot table